# Using count in three joint tables in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, count

**Script 1**

```
select supplier.suppl_no, name, count(art_no) TotalArticles 
from article, supplier 
where article.suppl_no = supplier.suppl_no and supplier.suppl_no = 20009
group by supplier.suppl_no, name;
```

Result: TotalArticles = 51

**Script 2**

```
select supplier.suppl_no, name, count(ord_no) TotalOrders 
from orders, supplier 
where orders.suppl_no = supplier.suppl_no and supplier.suppl_no = 20009
group by supplier.suppl_no, name;
```

Result: TotalOrders = 74

Now, I want to combine above two scripts in one as below.

**Script 3**

```
select article.suppl_no, name, count(art_no) "TotalArticles", count(ord_no) "TotalOrders" 
from article, supplier, orders 
where article.suppl_no = supplier.suppl_no and supplier.suppl_no = orders.suppl_no and supplier.suppl_no = 20009
group by article.suppl_no, name
```

Result: TotalArticles = 3774 (Expected 51 as in the first script)
Result: TotalOrders = 3774 (Expected 74 as in the second script)

So, here for bothe TotalArticles and TotalOrders, it's giving me the result 51 * 74 = 3774. Could you please help me to figure out what mistake I am doing in script 3? Many thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (Mark code and click `{}`. Add line-breaks where needed.)

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result. Here you find something useful to build a [mcve]

Comment: Try `count(distinct art_no)` and see what happens. (Or keep original queries.)

Answer (score 1):

You have one to many relation so join multiplicate rows. Either use `distinct`:

```
select a.suppl_no, name, count(distinct art_no) "TotalArticles", count(distinct ord_no) "TotalOrders" 
from article a inner join supplier s on (a.suppl_no = s.suppl_no) inner join orders o on (s.suppl_no = o.suppl_no)
where s.suppl_no = 20009
group by a.suppl_no, name;
```

Or produce counts in `with` statement:

```
with co as (
  select s.suppl_no, name, count(ord_no) TotalOrders 
    from orders o inner join supplier s on (o.suppl_no = s.suppl_no)
    where s.suppl_no = 20009
    group by s.suppl_no, name),
ca as (
  select s.suppl_no, name, count(art_no) TotalArticles 
    from article a inner join supplier s on (a.suppl_no = s.suppl_no)
    where s.suppl_no = 20009
    group by s.suppl_no, name)
select s.suppl_no, ca.TotalArticles, co.TotalOrders 
  from supplier, ca, co 
  where s.suppl_no = 20009;
```

In both you should use implicit joins, aliases also makes query more readable

Comment: Thanks a lot. As per your suggestion I just added 'distinct' and it gave me the expected result :)

count( distinct art_no) "TotalArticles", count( distinct ord_no) "TotalOrders"

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
        select a.suppl_no,name,
        count(a.art_no) "TotalArticles", 
        count(o.ord_no) "TotalOrders"
        from article a 
        inner join on  supplier s on a.suppl_no = s.suppl_no and s.suppl_no = 20009
        inner join on  orders o on o.suppl_no = s.suppl_no  
        group by article.suppl_no, name
```

Comment: This make no sense. You join orders table with njo condition on orders. So it goes cross join.

Comment: Thanks :) It worked after a bit of correction and adding 'count'



`select a.suppl_no, name,
        count(distinct a.art_no) "TotalArticles", 
        count(distinct o.ord_no) "TotalOrders"
        from article a 
        inner join supplier s on a.suppl_no = s.suppl_no and s.suppl_no = 20009
        inner join orders o on o.suppl_no = s.suppl_no  
        group by a.suppl_no, name;`